# How do I uninstall pwndbg?

Tags: linux, debian, git, clone, gdb

Not much explaining to do, except I Googled how to and couldn't find anything relating to the uninstall process. I am on a Debian 9 system.

If I recall correctly I installed it using:

```
git clone https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg
cd pwndbg
./setup.sh
```

I am a relative newbie to Linux so any help on this would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `setup.sh` to see what the script did to install the software. It's not particularly daunting. After all, you *are* asking a question about a *reverse engineering debugger*!

The last thing the installer does is add this line (with $PWD expanded to the path of your git clone) to your `~/.gdbinit` file .

```
source $PWD/gdbinit.py
```

If you remove that line, you will effectively disable pwndbg.

Then you are free to remove the `pwndbg` directory  (the git clone).

The setup script also installed (via pip) the Python packages listed in the `requirements.txt` file.  In general you can `pip uninstall` the ones you don't want. But you need to be careful - using Pip to install packages can end up overriding the ones your distro package manager has installed, leading to incompatibilities.

Pwndbg should really use `virtualenv` to set up a virtual environment just for itself, to avoid interfering with the dis to packages.

Related:

- [Don't Break Debain](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)